# Spring boot application never calling garbage collector

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot 2.6 application server with java 11. Even if i don't have memory leaks, my application never frees memory, and after some days it consumes many gigabytes and freeze the server. I solved this problem calling manually `System.gc()`.
This frees all the memory and prevent server freezing. But I do not like this solution at all and still i can't understand: why system never calls garbage collector? Why do i need to call it manually? Please help.

Comment: If it doesn't cleanup you actually do have a memory leak or some weird constructs that prevents GC from kicking in. Nonetheless your question contains too little information to pinpoint you into the direction.

Comment: I have a singleton entitymanager, injected by @PersistenceContext, that probably is caching many entities. But i manually evict all these entities and i'm pretty sure i don't have macroscopic memory leaks. And if i had sone leaks manually calling garbage collector woudn't resolve anything, because a memory leak is some object that is still referred by someone and can't be destroyed.

Comment: I know what a memory leak is, but it can be that the analyzer cannot detect, for some weird reason, that something is still holding on and doesn't do a GC. But as stated without seeing more of your application this is simply impossible to answer. What you need to do is attach a profiler to your application and see where the memory is being held and fix that.